# How to set inherit default group and permission setting to a CustomUser?

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a CustomUser to add new fields to the existing User class. I just want to default to User setting for group and permission controls for my CustomUser so I can use the default UserAdmin view.

How do I inherit the default group and permission (what do I have to add to my CustomUser class?)?

Comment: you want to set default value for group and permissions when a user is created, that's right?

Comment: correct! That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `post_signal` signal to configure the default user permissions. Use the `name` attribute of `Permission` object to get them.

Here is an example :

```python
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def define_default_user_permissions(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # retrieve needed permissions
    # E.g : permission to add a token
    permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can add token')
    # add this permission to the user
    instance.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Add this  method at the end of your `<app_name>.models`. Read more about [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/)

If you want to display all permissions, open your python shell with `python manage.py shell` and do this :

```python
# import Permission object
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
# display all permissions
Permission.objects.all()
```

Read more about [Models Meta - permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#permissions)  to know how to create permissions for your models

**You can do the same thing to define default groups to a new user with `Group` object.**

Comment: Then how how do you just set permissions and group to default? I assume there must be a default.

Comment: @HC I updated my answer with a complete new solution and concrete example to implement it.